# EPPlus:User define function calculate

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, vba

I want to use EPPlus to input data and calculate it.
[image: Here is my excel files and user defined function]
Here is my code:

```
ExcelWorksheet sheet = ep.Workbook.Worksheets["input"];
sheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = 10;
ep.Workbook.Calculate();
string test = sheet.Cells[1, 5].Text;
ep.Save();
```

The string test is "#NAME?"

It seems that EPPlus did not load user define function.

When I open the saved file, the calculation will be done automatically.

What should I do to make the user defined function work?

(I'll use this feature later in the ASP.NET to call User define functions in exist excel file.I tried Interop, it can achieve what I want, but a lot slower.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula calc engine in EPPlus cannot execute VBA functions in the workbook. It supports approx. 150 common built in Excel formulas and nothing more than that.

However, you can implement your VBA functions in .NET code. Each function should inherit the EPPlus class *ExcelFunction* and be registred to EPPlus via the Workbook.FormulaParserManager given the same function name as your VBA functions.

There are samples that illustrates this (create custom functions) in the EPPlus Samples project which can be downloaded from Codeplex.

For version 4.1, you can download the solution "EPPlus with samples" here:

https://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/625020

Then goto the "EPPlusSamples" project and check out *SampleAddFormulaFunction.cs*

Comment: Maybe you should reference to any link (in addition to your answer) which guides to the documentation or samples you refer to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a vba project in Epplus which is where you would define the function.  Something like this:

```
var fileinfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\UserDefinedFunctionTest.xlsm");
if (fileinfo.Exists)
    fileinfo.Delete();

var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Function test(a)");
sb.AppendLine("    test = a * 3");
sb.AppendLine("End Function");

using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileinfo))
{
    var workbook = package.Workbook;
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

    workbook.CreateVBAProject();
    var mod1 = workbook.VbaProject.Modules.AddModule("Module1");
    mod1.Code = sb.ToString();

    worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = 5;
    worksheet.Cells["A2"].Formula = "=test(A1)";

    package.Save();
}
```

Which will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Your method is possible, but still use the office open will be calculated.
If in C # the function will still not work.
Like following：
[link](http://i.imgur.com/RWygARp.png)

Comment: @Chao if you are expecting to see the calculated value in c# for that cell then unfortunately it will not.  Eppus just creates the raw XML files in a ZIP container.  The actual calculations will not happen until excel opens it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set formula in `ExcelWorkSheet`

`sheet.Cells[5, 5].Formula = "=A1*3";`

This is for first row only , if you want to do in Large number of rows then you have to use loop and inside loop use formula.

Comment: The EXCEL function in the image is just an experiment, because after that I will build more complex functions.
So only use EXCEL provided formula is not enough for me.